# How to Change Routing controller in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, routes

I have a problem, I want to create a specific routing for the controller, as in the example below :

www.mysite.com/Home/Company/3

to

www.mysite.com/CompanyName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.Net Core, you can setup routing middleware by using below code in "Configure" method:

In below code, if you dont want other paths (in defaultRoute) then you can remove it.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("specialRoute", 
                                  "CompanyName/{*action}", 
                      defaults: new { controller = "CompanyName", 
                                      action = "action" 
                                    });
                routes.MapRoute("defaultRoute", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```